# What is the best way for filter large number of record in Asp.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, sorting, grid, filtering

I've large number of record and I need to filter and sort by ascending/descending in grid.

Grid is also with pagination due to large number of data.

So in this case which is best way to implement for grid with high performance on load grid bind time and filter and search time.

Answer (score 0):

try to use Kendo UI Web Components. they will do all those things very efficiently.

Comment: If I'm not wrong than kendo load first all data for pagination than after it's take data for perticular page

Comment: if we specify serverPaging then it will load data on the paging request.
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/serverpaging